# Нахождение количества символов в строках файла

Tags: c

В данном фрагменте кода я хотел найти количество символов в каждой строке входного файла, т.е. записать в массив count количество для каждой строки, но программа просто виснет и ничего не выдает. Изначально k=0.

```
    while(!feof(fin))
    {
        while((c=getc(fin))!='\n' && !feof(fin))
        {
            if(c=='"')
                count[k]++;
        }
        k++;
        count=(int*)realloc(count,(k+1)*sizeof(int));
    }
```

Весь код: (задача в нахождении самого короткого слова, состоящего из загланых букв, начинающихся на A, за слово считается набор символов, заключенный в двойные кавычки). Считается, что в каждой строке файла четное кол-во кавычек.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int search(const char *SInputFile, char *word)
{
    FILE *fin;
    fin=fopen(SInputFile,"r");
    int k=0,s=0,*count,*length,i,j,best=-1,min=513,flag=0;
    char **a,c;
    if(!fin)
    {
        word[0]='F';
        fclose(fin);
        return -1;
    }
    count=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    while(!feof(fin))
    {
        while((c=getc(fin))!='\n' && !feof(fin))
        {
            if(c=='"')
                count[k]++;
        }
        k++;
        count=(int*)realloc(count,(k+1)*sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    if(count[i]%2!=0)
    {
        word[0]='I';
        fclose(fin);
        return 0;
    }
    fseek(fin,0,SEEK_SET);
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        s+=count[i];
    s=s/2;
    a=(char**)malloc(s*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
        a[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    length=(int*)malloc(s*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
        length[i]=0;
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        j=0;
        while((c=getc(fin))!='"');
        while((c=getc(fin))!='"')
        {
            if(c!='"')
                a[i][j]=c;
            j++;
            a[i]=(char*)realloc(a[i],j+1);
        }
        length[i]=j;
    }
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        flag=0;
        if(length[i]<min && a[i][0]=='A')
        {
            for(j=0;j<length[i];j++)
                if(a[i][j]<65 || a[i][j]>90)
                {
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
        }
        else
            flag=1;
        if(flag==0)
        {
            best=i;
            min=length[i];
        }
    }
    if(best==-1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<s;i++)
            free(a[i]);
        free(a);
        free(length);
        fclose(fin);
        return 0;
    }
    for(j=0;j<length[best];j++)
        word[j]=a[best][j];
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
        free(a[i]);
    free(a);
    free(length);
    free(count);
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char name[512],word[512]={0};
    int i;
    if(scanf("%s",name)!=1)
    {
        printf("File name wasn't entered.");
        return -1;
    }
    search(name,word);
    if(word[0]=='F')
        printf("File doesn't exist.");
    if(word[0]=='I')
        printf("Invalid input data.");
    if(word[0]==0)
        printf("There is not necessary word here.");
    if(word[0]!='I' && word[0]!='F')
    for(i=0;i<512;i++)
    {
        if(word[i]!=0)
            printf("%c",word[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Показали бы еще окружающий код, как вы его вызываете. Информации мало - может, виснет в другом месте? Здесь есть недочеты, но к зависанию они вести не должны...

Comment: Да, конечно, приложил код.

Answer (score 0):

Я исправил код: убрал лишний

```
while((c=getc(fin))=='"' && !feof(fin))
```

И вместо count[i] использовал просто переменную count; вот исправленный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int search(const char *SInputFile, char *word)
{
    FILE *fin;
    fin=fopen(SInputFile,"r");
    int s=0,count=0,*length,i,j,best=-1,min=513,flag=0;
    char **a,c;
    if(!fin)
    {
        word[0]='F';
        return -1;
    }
    while(!feof(fin))
    {
        if((c=getc(fin))=='"')
            count++;
        if(c=='\n' || feof(fin))
        {
            if(count%2==1)
            {
                word[0]='I';
                fclose(fin);
                return 0;
            }
            s+=count;
            count=0;
        }
    }
    s=s/2;
    fseek(fin,0,SEEK_SET);
    a=(char**)malloc(s*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
        a[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    length=(int*)malloc(s*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
        length[i]=0;
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        j=0;
        while((c=getc(fin))!='"');
        while((c=getc(fin))!='"')
        {
            if(c!='"')
                a[i][j]=c;
            j++;
            a[i]=(char*)realloc(a[i],j+1);
        }
        length[i]=j;
    }
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        flag=0;
        if(length[i]<min && a[i][0]=='A')
        {
            for(j=0;j<length[i];j++)
                if(a[i][j]<65 || a[i][j]>90)
                {
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
        }
        else
            flag=1;
        if(flag==0)
        {
            best=i;
            min=length[i];
        }
    }
    if(best==-1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<s;i++)
            free(a[i]);
        free(a);
        free(length);
        fclose(fin);
        return 0;
    }
    for(j=0;j<length[best];j++)
        word[j]=a[best][j];
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
        free(a[i]);
    free(a);
    free(length);
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char name[512],word[512]={0};
    int i;
    if(scanf("%s",name)!=1)
    {
        printf("File name wasn't entered.");
        return -1;
    }
    search(name,word);
    if(word[0]=='F')
        printf("File doesn't exist.");
    if(word[0]=='I')
        printf("Invalid input data.");
    if(word[0]==0)
        printf("There is not necessary word here.");
    if(word[0]!='I' && word[0]!='F')
    for(i=0;i<512;i++)
    {
        if(word[i]!=0)
            printf("%c",word[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то тяжеловесно кажется... Может, так?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    #define  BUFSIZE 512
    char s[BUFSIZE], word[BUFSIZE];
    int min = BUFSIZE;
    printf("Filename: ");
    fgets(s,BUFSIZE,stdin);
    s[strlen(s)-1] = 0;
    FILE * f = fopen(s,"rt");
    if (f == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can not open %s\n",s);
        return 1;
    }
    while(fgets(s,BUFSIZE,f))
    {
        for(char * b = strchr(s,'"'), *q; b; b = strchr(q,'"'))
        {
            char * e = strchr(b+1,'"'); // Всегда есть - четное число кавычек!
            *e = 0;  q = e+1;
            if (e - b - 1 >= min || b[1] != 'A') continue;
            int up = 1;
            for(char * c = b+1; c < e; ++c)
                if (!isupper(*c)) { up = 0; break; }
            if (!up) continue;
            strcpy(word,b+1);
            min = strlen(word);
        }
    }
    if (min == BUFSIZE)
        printf("There are no such words\n");
    else
        printf("This is word \"%s\"\n",word);
}
```